# Send to USB attached touch screen monitor with xrandr

Tags: usb, display, xrandr

I have a project which involves buying a [5'' inch USB Touch Screen](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/5-inch-usb-capacitive-touch-screen-panel-overlay-for-rasperry-pi) (from Raspberry Pi) to create an "info" screen: to control brightness, volume, current music, open shortcuts, etc...

I have the following questions:

- Does `xrandr` detect USB screens?
- Does `xrandr` work with touch screens?
- Since `xrandr` will see this as a multi-monitor setup, can I prevent the cursor from entering the second USB screen (but still being capable of touch controls)?

Comment: probably https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink . For the touch part (again probably) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation#Limit_Range

Comment: @Ric Subtil : why did you tag this with the "touch" tag. The touch tag is not applicable to your question. Please remove the touch tag.

Comment: @RahulKhimasia because my issue is related to touch screens.

Comment: @Ric the touch tag is for the unix touch command. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html .